# ffmpeg webm to lossless h264 or avi

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have a webm video file with VP9 60fps video and Opus 160kbps audio.
I need to convert it into Cineform for editing in Adobe however, I know there might not be a direct route available so I want to convert it to a lossless format before I can convert it to cineform with Adobe Media Encoder.
There is no specific requirement for this intermediate file and anything except uncompressed YUV 4:2:0 is acceptable. I tried ffmpeg to lossless h264 and it seems to work fine however I cannot get lossless audio output from ffmpeg. I tried PCM 16-bit but the output file is buggy!
Can someone please suggest a command line that outputs webm to lossless avi (huffyuv/lagarth/UtVideo/or_anything_else) with PCM audio or seperate commands for lossless h264 and lossless PCM (since mp4 container does not supports PCM).

Comment: What's buggy about the PCM audio?

Comment: Its a bad PCM which doesn't works.. Only 1 sec of static followed by error. MediaInfo can't show any details as well. EDIT: The encoding succeeds in ffmpeg, the error is in playback.

Comment: Show the full console output of the command you ran.

Comment: I'm using 'ffmpeg -i input.ogg -f s16le -acodec pcm_s16le output.wav'

Output at https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9TRF9IopyWFQVR3eXJFMTZXdTQ/view

Comment: Remove the `-f s16le` - that's a raw file - in fact, just use `ffmpeg -i input.ogg output.wav`. If you output to MOV, you can have lossless H.264 and WAV.

Comment: Thanks a ton! That worked. Also, thanks for the mov suggestion. That should do what I am after..

Answer (score 2):

This will convert lossless video (x264) / audio (wav) in a .mov.

```
ffmpeg -i video.webm -y -vcodec libx264 -qp 0 -pix_fmt yuv420p -acodec pcm_s32le video.mov
```

Comment: I wouldn't use -pix_fmt yuv444p, the source (webm) is likely yuv420p, and the conversion from 420p to 444p will make the source data much larger without being of any use.

Comment: @RonaldS.Bultje I see, I'll change it to yuv420p.